# Centering inline-block unordered lists results in second list forced to bottom

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am attempting to center two unordered lists inside a `div`. To do this, I am using this basic strategy, the crux of which is giving the parent `div` a `text-align: center` property and then making the child `ul`s `inline-block`s:

```css
.area {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 75px;
}
.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block
}
.list li {
  border: 1px solid pink;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="area">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>sup</li>
    <li>sup</li>
    <li>sup</li>
    <li>sup</li>
    <li>sup</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

However, the two list items in the second `ul` are positioned at the bottom instead of beginning at the top.

Floating seems to fix this particular issue, but then it seems like I have to do a clearfix to the parent `div` in order for it to match the `height` of the child `ul`s and, in addition, my two `ul`s are no longer nicely centered.

Is there a way to get that second `ul` in line with the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set `vertical-align:top` in `.list` because an element set `inline-block` by default  is `vertical-align:baseline`

```css
.area {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 75px;
}
.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top
}
.list li {
  border: 1px solid pink;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="area">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>sup</li>
    <li>sup</li>
    <li>sup</li>
    <li>sup</li>
    <li>sup</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```